# how can I assign the same bones to 2 objects?

Tags: bones

so I downloaded a [model](https://www.models-resource.com/custom_edited/cavestorycustoms/model/52945/) and the scene collection looks like this

[image]

I want to add him a skeleton but when I'm done the weight only applies to the inner model and the outline stays idle I'm new to blender so I don't know how to do it please help me

*(also it looks all black, it's suposed to have a black outline made of another model or idk this isn't part of my question but I'll like to know how to make him look good)*

Comment: Both objects need to be parented to the armature, not just the inner or the outer one. So if you for example parented the object to the armature through _Ctrl+P > Set Parent To > Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights_, you should have done this both. Either one after another or you could also select both models at the same time and then the armature at last, to parent the inner and outer model to the armature. If you didn't do it automatically, well then you have to do whatever method you used for the first one again for the second one.

Comment: thank you very much gordon